# Qual é a melhor tradução de "cachottier" em língua portuguesa?

Tags: significado, tradução, vocabulário

Quanto ao vocábulo **cachottier** em língua francesa, trata-se de um adjetivo definido como "*[En parlant d'une pers. ou de sa manière d'être] Qui fait des mystères, des cachotteries à propos de tout. Des manières cachottières* (Ao se referir a uma pessoa ou sua maneira de ser: Que faz mistérios, segredinhos a respeito de tudo)."

O Dicionário Infopédia o define e traduz como "segredista". Penso, no entanto, ser esse vocábulo pouco evocativo em língua portuguesa.

Em espanhol, encontrei *cachottier* traduzido por "*tramposo*", isto é, trapaceiro,traidor, vigarista, enganador.

Em inglês, encontrei o vocábulo traduzido por "*sneak*", isto é, furtivo, dedo-duro.

Qual seria a melhor tradução de **cachottier** em português?

Comment: teria mais informações sobre alguma frase para dar um contexto?

Comment: Tens *segredeiro* e *segredista*. Por mais que nunca os tenha ouvido, o significado é óbvio por causa do sufixo: "segredo" + "-eiro", "segredo" + "-ista".  São sufixos comuns, principalmente "-eiro", então, fica fácil de entender.

Answer (score 4):

Algumas sugestões de forma geral:

Uma pessoa que [esconde o jogo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/esconder%20o%20jogo)

> esconder o jogo: Dissimular.

E também pessoa [dissimulada](https://dicionario.priberam.org/dissimulado), porque pode ser a respeito de qualquer coisa.

> dissimulado
> (particípio de dissimular)
>
> adjetivo
>
> 1. Que se dissimulou ou escondeu.
> 2. Que tem o hábito da dissimulação. ≠ AUTÊNTICO, >VERDADEIRO
> 3. Disfarçado, encoberto.
> 4. Disposto de modo a não ser notado ou ser pouco >notado.
>
> adjetivo e substantivo masculino
>
> 5. Que ou o que mostra algo que não corresponde àquilo >que pensa ou sente. = FALSO, FINGIDO, HIPÓCRITA

Answer (score 0):

Sou um mero estudante de francês e não conhecia essa palavra. Segundo o meu dicionário, *cachotterie* é um segredinho sem importância, e um *cachottier*, alguém que gosta de ficar de segredinhos. Como sinônimos aparecem misterioso e camuflado (dissimulado), e antônimos livro aberto e revelador. Gosto da sugestão de dissimulado do sumitani, mas aqui no Brasil, pelo menos, é um termo um tanto agressivo.

Juntando as definições que encontramos, eu sugiro algo como **sigiloso**, **discreto**. Depende muito do contexto.